# Hazelcast and MapDB - implementing a simple distributed database

Tags: java, hazelcast, mapdb, nosql

I have implemented a hazelcast service which stores its data into local mapdb instances via MapStoreFactory and newMapLoader. This way the keys can be loaded if a cluster restart is necessary:

```
public class HCMapStore<V> implements MapStore<String, V> {

Map<String, V> map;

/** specify the mapdb e.g. via 
  * DBMaker.newFileDB(new File("mapdb")).closeOnJvmShutdown().make() 
  */
public HCMapStore(DB db) {
    this.db = db;
    this.map = db.createHashMap("someMapName").<String, Object>makeOrGet();
}

// some other store methods are omitted
@Override
public void delete(String k) {
    logger.info("delete, " + k);
    map.remove(k);
    db.commit();
}

// MapLoader methods
@Override
public V load(String key) {
    logger.info("load, " + key);
    return map.get(key);
}

@Override
public Set<String> loadAllKeys() {
    logger.info("loadAllKeys");
    return map.keySet();
}

@Override
public Map<String, V> loadAll(Collection<String> keys) {
    logger.info("loadAll, " + keys);
    Map<String, V> partialMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String k : keys) {
        partialMap.put(k, map.get(k));
    }
    return partialMap;
}}
```

The problem I'm now facing is that the loadAllKeys method of the MapLoader interface from hazelcast requires to return ALL keys of the whole cluster BUT every node stores ONLY the objects it owns.

Example: I have two nodes and store 8 objects, then e.g. 5 objects are stored in the mapdb of node1 and 3 in the mapdb of node2. Which object is owned by which node is decided by hazelcast I think. Now on restart node1 will return 5 keys for loadAllKeys and node2 will return 3. Hazelcast decides to ignore the 3 items and data is 'lost'.

**What could be a good solution to this?**

**Update for bounty**: [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/t91IToUX3AE) I asked this on the hc mailing list mentioning 2 options (I'll add 1 more) and I would like to know if something like this is already possible with hazelcast 3.2 or 3.3:

1. Currently the MapStore interface gets only data or updates from the local node. Would it be possible to notify the MapStore interface of every storage action of the full cluster? Or maybe this is already possible with some listener magic? Maybe I can force hazelcast to put all objects into one partition and have 1 copy on every node.
2. If I restart e.g. 2 nodes then the MapStore interface gets called correctly with my local databases for node1 and then for node2. But when both nodes join the data of node2 will be removed as Hazelcast assumes that only the master node can be correct. Could I teach hazelcast to accept the data from both nodes?

Answer (score 2):

According to Hazelcast 3.3 documentation
the MapLoader initialization flow is the following:

> When getMap() is first called from any node, initialization will start
>   depending on the the value of InitialLoadMode. If it is set as EAGER,
>   initialization starts. If it is set as LAZY, initialization actually
>   does not start but data is loaded at each time a partition loading is
>   completed.
>
> 1. Hazelcast will call MapLoader.loadAllKeys() to get all your keys on
>      each node
> 2. Each node will figure out the list of keys it owns
> 3. Each node will load all its owned keys by calling
>      MapLoader.loadAll(keys)
> 4. Each node puts its owned entries into the map by calling
>      IMap.putTransient(key,value)

The above implies that if nodes start up in a different order then the keys will get distributed differently too. Thus, each node won't find all/some of the assigned keys in its local store. You should be able to verify it by setting breakpoints in your HCMapStore.loadAllKeys and HCMapStore.loadAll and compare the keys you re get retrieved with the keys that.

In my opinion, what you are trying to achieve contradicts the concept of distributed cache with resilience characteristics like Hazelcast and therefore is impossible. I.e. when one node goes away (fails or disconnects for whatever reason) the cluster will rebalance by moving parts of data around, the same process will happen every time a node joins a cluster. So, in case of cluster changes the local backstore of the lost node becomes out-of-date.

Hazelcast cluster is dynamic by nature, hence it can't rely on backstore with static distributed topology. Essentially, you need to have a shared backstore to make it work with dynamic hazelcast cluster. The backstore can be distributed as well, e.g. cassandra, but its topology must be independent from cache cluster topology.

UPDATE: It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve is more logical in the form of a distributed datastore (on top of MapDB) with local caching.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps two options:

1) Dig into how partitioning works in Hazelcast. I think there could be way to have MapLoader per partition, and force node to load only its own partitions, this would solve conflicts.

2) when node comes back online, interact with Hazelcast cluster before node is added. You could merge two sets one from HZ second from MapDB.

3) force Hazelcast to store all data on every node. Set partition number to 1 or something

Comment: Thanks - options are good ideas, but I would like to know how I would do something like that and if that is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to load data stored on all nodes but at the moment you'd have to do it manually.

On each node:

```
HCMapStore store = createMapDbStore();
HazelcastInstance hz = createHz( store ); // use store in MapStoreConfig as implementation
IMap imap = hz.getMap("map"); 
Map diskMap = store.loadAll( store.loadAllKeys() ); // load all entries on disk
imap.putAll( diskMap ); // put into distributed map
```

But as mentioned in the mailing list `MapStore` is not really intended to be used this way. Also be aware that backups are not persisted to disk in this way. So if you restart your cluster and the disk on one node dies, those entries will be lost.

Comment: Thanks! This means there is a 'shard' concept called 'partitions', but no replica concept? If those entries will be lost, how does HC makes sure that it does not lose data if a node dies?

Comment: @Karussell Entries are backed up in memory on multiple nodes. If a node dies while the cluster is running its fine. But with this kind of local persistence backups are not stored on disk. So if you shutdown your cluster, then try to start it and one disk doesn't start because its dead ...

Comment: I see and there is no way to access this in-memory backup somehow?

Comment: Not really, they're not exposed via the API

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be [not easily possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/file$20storage/hazelcast/A8BUfNk4KsQ/Ndn0Zq4YaIcJ):

> The persistance layer for Hazelcast requires it to be some sort of
>   central storage. Like database, or shared file.

or look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/file$20storage/hazelcast/PsOPUaSJuFA/PiZD8Gi1crQJ) or [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/file$20storage/hazelcast/S_pK1yZ9HbA/_THphFEDvqUJ). Will look into OrientDB which is using Hazelcast and persists to disc.